# How do I loop through a regex's matches inside a replace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, lambda, match

I have the following JavaScript (the spaces in the `<P>`s are non-breaking):

```
var html = '...<li>sub 2</li></ol></li></ol>\n\
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; i.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; subsub 1</p>\n\
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ii.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; subsub 2</p>\n\
<ol start="2"> \n\
<ol start="3"> \n\
<li>sub 3</li></ol>...';

$(function () {
    var nestedListFixer = /(?:<\/li><\/ol>\s*)+(?:<p>(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+(?:\s[ivxlcdm]+\.)(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+\s(.*?)<\/p>\s*)+(?:<ol(?:\sstyle=\"[^\"]+\")?\sstart=\"[^\"]+\">\s*)+/i;
    html = html.replace(nestedListFixer, function($0, $1){
        var lis = ""
        $.each($1, function () {
            lis += "<li>" + this + "</li>\n";
        });
        alert("<ol>\n" + lis + "</ol></li>");
        return "<ol>\n" + lis + "</ol></li>";
    });
});
```

The `alert()`'s output:

```
<ol>
<li>s</li>
<li>u</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>s</li>
<li>u</li>
<li>b</li>
<li> </li>
<li>2</li>
</ol></li>
```

Here's what I hoped it would be:

```
<ol>
<li>subsub 1</li>
<li>subsub 2</li>
</ol></li>
```

How do I correctly loop through each match in the `$1`?

**Update:** simplified pattern and matching example:

```
var text = '1ab2cb3cd4ab5cb6cd7';

$(function () {
    var textFixer = /(?:a)(?:b(.*?)c)+(?:d)/i;
    text = text.replace(textFixer, function($0, $1){
        var numbers = "";
        $.each($1, function () {
            numbers += this;
        });
        alert(numbers);
        return numbers;
    });
    alert(text);
});

// actual text:
// 13467
// desired text:
// 1234567
```

Comment: Can you not simplify your code, regex, and markup so people can more easily understand your problem and therefore help you more? (Not a rhetorical question)

Comment: I've added a simpler version, does that make more sense?

Comment: Wait, "can you not..." were you saying I had already simplified it too much?

Comment: No, I was requesting a simpler version, which is what you did. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that I came up with but it doesn't seem to be very efficient:

```
$(function () {
    var nestedListFixer = /(?:<\/li><\/ol>\s*)+(?:<p>(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+(?:\s[ivxlcdm]+\.)(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+\s(.*?)<\/p>\s*)+(?:<ol(?:\sstyle=\"[^\"]+\")?\sstart=\"[^\"]+\">\s*)+/gi;
    var nestedListItem = /<p>(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+(?:\s[ivxlcdm]+\.)(?:&(?:nbsp|\#0*160|x0*A0);)+\s(.*?)<\/p>\s*/gi;

    // fix nested lists
    html = html.replace(nestedListFixer, function($0, $1){
        var lis = ""
        $.each($0.match(nestedListItem), function () {
            lis += "<li>" + this.replace(nestedListItem, "$1") + "</li>\n";
        });
        return "<ol>\n" + lis + "</ol></li>";
    });
});
```

...or for the simpler example above:

```
$(function () {
    var textFixer = /(?:a)(?:b(.*?)c)+(?:d)/gi;
    var textItem = /b(.*?)c/gi;

    text = text.replace(textFixer, function($0, $1){
        var numbers = "";
        $.each($0.match(textItem), function () {
            numbers += this.replace(textItem, "$1");
        });
        return numbers;
    });
});
```

Doing a `.replace()` substitution, inside a loop of a `.match()` array, inside of a custom `.replace()` function just doesn't seem like it is very economical. It does give me the output that I was looking for though.

Answer (score 5):

The updated example you've given would only match "3" not "13467" as you described.  If you change your regexp to do global matching, it would return "36" and still not the "13467".

Your first example doesn't output anything either.

Are you just trying to get matches to the regular expression and loop through the matches?

If so,

```
var text = '1ab2cb3cd4ab5cb6cd7';
var matches = text.match(/(\d)/g);
for (i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
   alert(matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: Close, I'm trying iterate through the matches of a particular group. so for "abcdcdef".match(/ab(cd)+ef/) how do I loop through multiple matches of $1?

Answer (score 1):

A pretty loop can be using hook pattern :

```
var text = '1ab2cb3cd4ab5cb6cd7';
text.match(/(\d)/g).forEach(function(element,index){
   console.log(element)
});
```