# Regex to find matches except in last n characters of input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to replace the digits in the first (n-4) characters of credit card with '*'.
I am using following three lines of code.

```
var cardnumber = '1A2C3GF4DS84Ff'; 
last4digits = cardNumber.substring(cardNumber.length-4);
prevdigits  = cardNumber.substring(0, cardNumber.length-4).replace(/[0-9]/g,'*');
$cache.cardNumber.val( prevdigits + last4digits);
```

Just wondering can I do it in just one line of code by using regex.

Comment: "first n occurrences of a character" - of what character ? how about `D` ?

Comment: @ l'L'l 1 @ RomanPerekhrest Updated my question

Comment: Earlier I was trying to make my question generic one while last three lines is the actual problem that I was facing. Anyway thanks for the solution.

Comment: @paraSelixiR Go ahead and accept an answer that you like.

Answer (score 3):

Use a look-ahead to ensure that there are at least four remaining characters after the digit. In other words, digits within the last four characters will not match:

```
var regexp = /\d(?=....)/g;

> cardnumber.match(regexp)
< ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

To replace with asterisks:

```
> cardnumber.replace(regexp, '*')
< "*A*C*GF*DS84Ff"
```

Information on look-aheads is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead).

Comment: Thanks that is whatI was looking for!

Comment: @NinaScholz Please see my clarifying question in a comment to the OP's question. In his response to that comment, the OP confirmed that the problem was to replace digits in all but the last four characters of the input. There are four such digits.

Comment: @paraSelixiR Nothing, I just thought it was a bit wordier. It works the same.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261985/how-do-i-loop-through-a-regexs-matches-inside-a-replace-in-javascript) I got this code.

```
var text = '1ab2cb3cd4ab5cb6cd7';
var matches = text.match(/(\d)/g);

for (i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
   alert(matches[i]);
}
```

Actually, they wanted to extract digits too. I don't need to change the regex.

You can limit it to 5 by making the loop start with:

```
for (i=0; i<matches.length && i < 5; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`(\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/yZ5aX0/2) and check it programmatically afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
var y= x.replace(/\D/g, '').substring(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.replace()` function can use a function as the replacement, and it will be called for each match. It can keep a counter and return something different based on the counter.

```js
var str = '1A2C3GF4DS84Ff';
var digits = 0;
var newstr = str.replace(/\d/g, function(match) {
  if (digits++ < 4) {
    return '*';
  } else {
    return match;
  }
});
document.write(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like following one does the job You need:

```
var text= '1A2B3C4D5E6F',
    n = 5;
text = text.replace(/\d/g, function ($1){
  return n-- ?'*' : $1
});
```

Comment: If I won't find any answer with regex then this is the only possible solution.

Comment: but this is actually using a Regexp, what do You mean then with 'answer with regex' ?

Comment: You would like to specify n into the regexp?..that's what You mean?

Comment: @torazaburo got it, nice to know!

Comment: I think he means a single regexp which matches exactly the characters he is interesting in replacing with asterisk.